# Getting null in control from input field

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, get

I'm stack. I Have a simple controller and visualforce page.
Controller:

```
public class  NewTaskSchedulerController {
    public Event Event {get; set;}

    public NewTaskSchedulerController(){
        Event = new Event();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        try{
            //Already getting null when I try to get the input value
            system.debug(Event.Activity_Location__c);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {            
            ApexPages.addMessages(exc);              
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here are my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="NewTaskSchedulerController">
    <apex:inputField value="{!event.Activity_Location__c}" id="loc"/>
    <apex:CommandButton value={!save}/>
<apex:page>
```

What I'm doing wrong?
In that case on button press I might get this value, but Event and also Event.Activity_Location__c is getting null value....

Comment: Are you sure your VF is correct, it does not have form tag in it. Also, can you change the instance name of Event to something else.

Comment: best practice: `public Event event {get; set;}` and `this.event = new Event();` if you like having variables whose name is the same as their type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you need to correct:-

1. `<apex:CommandButton value={!save}/>` Here, Value is actually the text displayed on the commandButton as its label.In order to call a method use action attribute. `<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="check"/>` is correct way to use.
2. An `<apex:commandButton>` component must always be a child of an `<apex:form>` component.
3. Also, You must close a tag if you have defined in your page. `<apex:page>` should be like `</apex:page>`

So, your visualforce page should like this:-

```
<apex:page controller="NewTaskSchedulerController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputField value="{!Event.Subject}" id="loc"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="check"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Read more about them here:-

1. [apex:commandButton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)
2. [apex:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm)